# How to print image file from a printer using QT

Tags: qt

I am trying to print an image file on printer using QWebview but instead of image blank page is printed. Please find the below code.

```
void ChartViewer::onprintBtnClicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open File",QString(),"Pdf File(*.png)");
    qDebug()<<"Print file name is "<<fileName;
    if(fileName.endsWith(".png"))
    {
        QPrinter printer;
        QWebView *view = new QWebView;
        QPrintDialog *dlg = new QPrintDialog(&printer,this);
        printer.setOutputFileName(fileName);
        if(dlg->exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
            return;
        view->load(fileName);
        view->print(&printer);
    }
}
```

If I use view->show() then it has shown the image properly but printed page is coming blank. Request you to please look into the above code and correct me where I am doing wrong.

Regards,
Lekhraj

Comment: If you format your code properly you might get more people interested in your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You load some png file into fileName. Then you set `QPrinter` to print to that png file with `printer.setOutputFileName(fileName);`.I suppose it is wrong, it should be some different pdf file probably.

I'm not sure if I understand what are you trying to do? How to print image file using QPrinter? Into pdf file? Why are trying to use QWebView?
You can use QImage to load image file and then paint with QPainter on QPrinter.

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0,"Open File",QString(),"PNG File(*.png)");

        QPrinter printer;
        QPrintDialog *dlg = new QPrintDialog(&printer,0);
        if(dlg->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
                QImage img(fileName);
                QPainter painter(&printer);
                painter.drawImage(QPoint(0,0),img);
                painter.end();
        }

        delete dlg;

        QTimer::singleShot(1, &app, SLOT(quit()));
        app.exec();
        return 0;
}
```

Some of your issues may overlap with your other question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297239/how-to-print-pdf-file-in-qt

Comment: Dear Lukas, I don't want to print image file using Qprinter on pdf file instead i want to take print of my existing image file.For example :- I have an image file named "test.png" and i have one printer machine.now i want that whenevr i run this program image file goes to printer machine and printer has print this image file.Please let me inform if question is still not clear.

Comment: Dear Lekhraj, I edited the code. Can you check if it works for you?
It should dislay dialog to open png file, then display dialog to select and configure the printer and when you click ok, selected image should be printed.

Comment: Dear Lukas, It's working very fine and now i am able to take printout of png file.But I also want to perform same action for pdf file but in case of pdf it's not working.If you have any idea then request you to please give me some hint.

Comment: @user671112 Ok, then maybe you can mark my answer as solution for this image case and we can continue in your original thread for PDF here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297239/how-to-print-pdf-file-in-qt

Answer (score 1):

You try to print the QWebView immediately after you call its load() function. But the QWebView has not yet loaded the content and the view is therefore blank. You need to connect the QWebView's [loadFinished](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebview.html#loadFinished) signal to some slot where you can call the print() function. Read the [QWebView's documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebview.html#details).