# How to print(with the printer) a QML object?

Tags: qt, printing, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have designed a sales receipt with Qt Quick and I want to print it with the printer.

How can I do this?

Here is my **main.cpp**

```
QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/Caisse-MBM/main.qml"));
viewer.showFullScreen();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `QQuickView::grabWindow()` to get a `QImage` and then do whatever you want with it, print it, save it...

```
QImage image = view->grabWindow();
```

Afterwards you can follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311217/991484) to get the image to print.

Comment: I don't have the **view** object in my cpp. And how to call a method which makes all of that from my QML files ?

Note : I have included my **main.cpp** in the question.

Comment: @slimit-tn - in your case it is `viewer`

Comment: No, the problem is that i want to execute **grabWindow()** on a child of a child of a child of the view object.

For that i have passed the QImage as a Context Parameter.

Comment: `grabWindow()` is only available for the quick view, if you want the graphical representation of an object you are in for a treat - I've been trying to get access to the raw framebuffer data but to no avail. If I find a way to do it I will let you know.