# Render a QML scene into a texture and save it

Tags: c++, qt, qml

How could I translate the QML scene(like Rectangle, Image etc) into a texture and save it?
Anyone tried this before?If I can translate the components to texture, then I should be able to save
the image after processing by particle systems or shaderEffects

Example:

```
Rectangle{
  id:root

  widht:640
  height: 480

  ToTexture{ id: toTexture} //a new type created by c++

  MouseArea{

     anchors.fill: parent

     onClicked: {         
         toTexture.saveAsTexture(root)
     }
  }
}
```

The problem is, how could I design a new type like ToTexture?
The example of " Scene Graph - OpenGL Under QML." show us how
to render a qml scene, but I can't find an example show us how
to transfer the qml scene to a texture.

Without this function, I can't save the graph generated QtQuick

Comment: With "the QML scene" do you literally mean an entire QML scene? In QtQuick2 that's trivial with QQuickWindow::setRenderTarget, and I pretty much guess it's the same in QQ1 by QDeclarativeView::render onto a QImage...

Comment: Precisely, I want to do what shaderEffectSource do, render Rectangle, Image and other components to texture and get the pointer of those texture, save the texture by QImage.

Comment: Any example? I found one called OpenGL Under QML，show us how to render the qml scene, but there are no example show us how to translate the qml scene into a texture and save it.In QtQuick2, we can't even simply transfer the Image to QImage and save it like QQ1 did.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792634/how-to-printwith-the-printer-a-qml-object/16793242#16793242

Comment: Thanks, ddriver, do you know how to extract the the raw framebuffer data of the visible qml component now?I would like to record the scene as video, but can't find a way to do so, grabWindow() is too slow for video

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, on this post

[take screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090019/how-to-take-screenshot-qt-qml/17091651#17091651)

We could take the screenshot of the qml scene, then we could do anything to it, include render it to texture