# How to take ScreenShot Qt/QML

Tags: qt, qml

[QtQuick1 example](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_take_ScreenShot_Qt/QML)
I can’t make it work on QtQuick2

screenCapture.hpp

```
#include <QObject>

class QString;
class QQuickView;

class screenCapture : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:    
    explicit screenCapture(QQuickView *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void capture(QString const &path) const;

private:
    QQuickView *currentView_;    
};
```

screenCapture.cpp

```
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QString>

#include "screenCapture.hpp"

screenCapture::screenCapture(QQuickView *currentView) :
    QObject(0), currentView_(currentView)
{
}

void screenCapture::capture(QString const &path) const
{
    QPixmap::grabWidget(currentView_).save(path);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "screenCapture.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<screenCapture>("Image", 1, 0, "ScreenCapture");
    qmlRegisterType<saveAbleImage>("Image", 1, 0, "SaveAbleImage");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QStringLiteral("/Users/Qt/program/experiment_apps_and_libs/funnyCamera/qml/funnyCamera/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    screenCapture screenClass(&view);
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("screenObject", &screenClass);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle{
    id : root
    width : 1024
    height : 768    

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: root

        onClicked: {          
            console.log("save image")
            screenObject.capture("Pictures/saveTest.jpg")
        }
    }
}
```

error message

QPixmap::grabWidget is deprecated, use QWidget::grab() instead
QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method QQuickView::grab(QRect)

Comment: For Qt5 QML Quick2 you can use this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146747/capture-qml-drawing-buffer-without-displaying

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution, pretty simple, change the function “capture” to

```
void screenCapture::capture(QString const &path) const
{
    QImage img = currentView_->grabWindow();
    img.save(path);
}
```