# QtQuick get render buffer

Tags: c++, qt, qml, bufferedreader, qtquick2

Hi guys.
I have to render some qml but do not show it and get it render data(buffer) and place it in another place. It is desirable that this could be done in another thread.

I have already found "needed" method [grabWindows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#grabWindow), but it performace is too low. Is this posible to do it using some private headers?

Will it help if I [compile qml](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/)?

Comment: maybe it could [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146747/capture-qml-drawing-buffer-without-displaying) But I need without displaying

Comment: There’s http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#grabToImage to grab items. I doubt it’s much faster though, they both use the same functions to dump the FBO contents into an image (which boils down to some sort of glReadPixels). I doubt there’s any threading possible due to how OpenGL works here.