# Render QML without being visible, like a background task

Tags: qml, qt5

Suppose I have a map, and a few polygons. I want to render them and take a screenshot of each one of them.
If the QQuickView is visible, thats easy.
But, how could I achieve this, with the QQuickView **not visible**, like a **background task**?

Any ideas?

I`m using Qt 5.12.

Comment: move them out of screen or whatever. but anyway, the render will not be a _background task_.  All the GUI renders, including the map will be executed sequentially.

Comment: It wont work moving the view out of screen, the Item::grabToImage call fails. Window must be visible. Any way to workaround this?