# QML Component Screen Rendering

Tags: qml, qt-quick

Is it possible to capture the screen rendering of a QML Component and save it to an image file? I would like to drive a Component through several different states, and capture its visual appearance for documentation purposes, without having to do screen/window captures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could set up your state transitions to call `QWidget::grab` then save it to a file through `QPixmap`.

If you need an example of how to set up your code to call `QWidget::grab` take a look at this answer: [How to take ScreenShot Qt/QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090019/how-to-take-screenshot-qt-qml)

It's important to replace `QPixmap::grabWidget` with `QWidget::grab` because `QPixmap::grabWidget` is now obsolete. Once you have the `QPixmap` from `QWidget::grab` follow the documentation in `QPixmap` to save to the format you'd like such as jpeg, png, gif.

Here are some links to the documentation to help you out.

[QWidget::grab](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#grab)

[QPixmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpixmap.html)

[QPixmap::save](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qpixmap.html#save)

Answer (score 2):

With Qt 5.4 it is now made easier with [grabToImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method) - this method resides on all QQuickItem objects.

**EDIT**
It's worth mentioning that the item you call grabToImage() on must be a child of a top-level [Window](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) item container