# QQuickWindow::grabWindow: scene graph already in use

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I tried the code shown here: [How to take ScreenShot Qt/QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090019/how-to-take-screenshot-qt-qml)

On execution I am getting the error written in the title.

My ***main.cpp*** is:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QImage>
#include <QDebug>
#include "screenshot.h"
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    const char* drigUi = "DrigUI"; 
    qmlRegisterType <screenCapture> (drigUi, 1, 0, "ScreenShot");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

I used this **capture** function:

```
void screenCapture::capture(QString const &path) const
{
    QImage img = currentView_->grabWindow();
    img.save(path);
}
```

and added the following in the constructor:

```
currentView_ = new QQuickView;
```

My ***main.qml*** :

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import DrigUI 1.0

Window
{
    visible: true
    height: 370
    width: 370

    ScreenShot { id: screenShot }

    Rectangle
    {
        id: ll
        height: 30
        width: 50
        x: 180; y: 0; color: "red"
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: screenShot.capture ("l.png")
        }
    }
}
```

What does that error mean? What is the way to solve it? What else info can I provide here?

Comment: You can provide your main.qml. Minimized to a SSCCE, that reproduce that problem.

Comment: @SaZ I delebrately didn't provide . It doesn't contain anything very important. Now, I will it here as you say.

Comment: @SaZ Done. what is SSCCE?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to put an assert to your `screenCapture::capture` method: `Q_ASSERT( QThread::currentThread() == qApp->thread() );`. There are some comments in documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#grabWindow

Comment: @SaZ How will I get qApp object in capture method. That object is in main.cpp. Isn't it?

Comment: `qApp` is on an object. It is a macro for `QApplication::instance` singleton. Try to use search before asking such questions ;)

Comment: @SaZ Well, I am not very wise. Your code gives me error: "qApp was not decalred in this scope". Why should I search Google on this error? That error does not indicate that it is a macro of anything.

Comment: Try `QGuiApplication::instance()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had posted this question on [QtCenter.org too, and got the enlightenment from there.](http://qtcenter.org/threads/63993-QQuickWindow-grabWindow-scene-graph-already-in-use?p=283181#post283181)

> My I ask why you want to create a screenshot of an empty QQuickView?
>   Wouldn't you want to take the screenshot of the Window you create in QML?

I realized that I wasn't using the `QQuickView` anywhere in `main.cpp`. so that meant that `QQuickView`, I was using, was empty.

My other part of program is using `QQuickWindow` instead of `QQuickView`, so I replaced `QQuickView` with `QQuickWindow` as follows:

**ScreenCapture.h**

```
#ifndef SCREENSHOT_H
#define SCREENSHOT_H

#include <QObject>

class QString;
class QQuickWindow;

class screenCapture : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit screenCapture (QQuickWindow *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void capture (QString const &path) const;

private:
    QQuickWindow *currentWindow;
};

#endif // SCREENSHOT_H
```

**ScreenCapture.cpp**

```
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QDebug>
#include "screenshot.h"

screenCapture::screenCapture(QQuickWindow *currentWindow) :
    QObject(0), currentWindow (currentWindow)
{
}

void screenCapture::capture (QString const &path) const
{
    QImage p = currentWindow->grabWindow ();
    bool kk = p.save (path);
    qDebug () << kk;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject      *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window   = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);

    screenCapture launcher (window);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ScreenShot", &launcher);

    window->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Now, in QML side, we can directly use

`ScreenShot.capture ("/home/*****/Desktop/l.png")`

anywhere we want. It works.