# Qt : How to grab a snapshot of a QQuickItem leaving out its child QQuickItems from the grabbed result

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qimage, qquickitem

My question is a follow up on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183743/what-would-be-the-way-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-particular-item-in-qml).

**Yes**. Following way of `grabToImage` can get me a snapshot of any particular `QQuickItem` like `parent_rect` below.

```
Rectangle {
    id: parent_rect
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: child_rect1
        width: parent.width/4
        height: parent.height/4
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: child_rect2
        width: parent.width/4
        height: parent.height/4
    }
}
// ...
parent_rect.grabToImage(function(result) {
                       result.saveToFile("something.png");
                   });
```

**Problem:**
But this `grabToImage` gets me the snapshot of the all its children as well namely `child_rect1` and `child_rect2`.

**Question:**
How can I get the snapshot of `parent_rect` only without getting its children add into the returned result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to hide the children and then restore visibility.

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    function grabWithoutChildren(item, filename){
        var isVisibleList = []
        var i
        for(i in item.children){
            isVisibleList[i] = item.children[i].visible
            item.children[i].visible = false
        }

        item.grabToImage(function(result) {
            result.saveToFile(filename)
            for(i in item.children){
                 item.children[i].visible = isVisibleList[i]
            }
        })
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: parent_rect
        width: 400
        height: 400
        color: "red"

        Rectangle {
            id: child_rect1
            width: parent.width/4
            height: parent.height/4
            color: "blue"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: child_rect2
            x: 10
            y: 10
            width: parent.width/4
            height: parent.height/4
            color: "green"

            Rectangle{
                x:50
                y:50
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: grabWithoutChildren(parent_rect, "something.png")
}
```

Comment: ok. at least this is one way. Qt should really add an API to QQuickItem class give this layer snapshot without having to do much. My search on the docs started with an expectation this would be a pretty normal thing to do. Thanks @eyllanesc

Comment: @Game_Of_Threads 
Should, but it seems that within their needs are not. My solution is simple so I think it's enough. if I help you, you could give it an upvote or mark it as correct :)

Comment: sure @eyllanesc