# Screenshot of QML item in C++ class

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My problem is the following:
In Qt 6.5.3, in a QML QApplication I need to periodically (every minute) make a screenshot of the QML ApplicationWindow. The screenshot is needed in a c++ class, that then sends the image via Bluetooth.

Could you help me with how to get a QImage of the GUI in the C++ class?

I tried to pass the QQmlApplicationEngine to the class and then get the rootObjects, cast to QQuickWindow and then grabWindow, but I couldn't manage to make it work.

Comment: Rather than saying "I couldn't manage to make it work", show us what you tried and explain what exactly didn't work. Did you get a compiler error? Did it crash?

Comment: Does this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33183166/1717300 ?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Qml items from C++ side is bad practice. It should be the other way around. Put a Q_INVOKABLE method inside a C++ class that your UI has access to and pass your screenshot to it.

```
    Q_INVOKABLE void setScreenShot(QImage image);
```

Qml Side :

```
    Timer { 
        interval: 60000 
        onTriggered: Window.contentItem.grabToImage(function (result) {
            viewModel.setScreenShot(result.image)
        })
    }
```