# Qt is unable to detect printers on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, printing

I'm using Qt for a project (Qt 5.0.2, precompiled and downloaded from qt-project.org) on Windows 7 (32-bit) and I'm having trouble trying to print a document.

```
qDebug() << QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters().size(); // 0
```

I'm able to print as PDF and I tested the same executable in other computers, it works just well. I do have printers installed and I can print normally from any other program such as notepad or Word. Any clue on why is it returning an empty list? I can't find this behavior documented anywhere, is this a Qt bug?

Comment: could you please provide more info about your environment (os, 32/64 or etc.)

Comment: @AnatolyS: Windows 7, 32-bit

Comment: do you run your application from QCreator or via command line?

Comment: @AnatolyS: From command line.

Comment: may be your application cannot find plugins which allow printing facilities (printingsupport directory must be in execution directory from qt the bin\plugins directory)

Comment: @AnatolyS: Oh, this was indeed missing. I'll make a second try soon. Thank you.

Comment: @AnatolyS: Unfortunately the problem was not solved by adding the missing DLL. The behavior didn't change.

Comment: @AnatolyS: I was using the wrong ´windowsprintersupport.dll´. Your suggestion actually worked, thank you. Make an answer of it so that I can accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you deploy your Qt application, you should put

```
[your Qt application]\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
```

The library windowsprintersupport.dll should be taken from

```
[Qt path]\[platform]\plugins\printsupport
```

P.S. The first answer is almost correct, except path's names.

Answer (score -2):

> May be your application cannot find plugins which allow printing
>   facilities (printingsupport directory must be in execution directory
>   from qt the bin\plugins directory).

This answer is moved from AnatolyS' comment.