# Qt How to Print QFile via QPrinter?

Tags: c++, qt, qprinter

Can any one suggest me a way to Print QFile using QPrinter ??

Actually, I have a pdf file generated by my application which i need to print (via dot matrix Printer) as per user choice.I searched QFile documentation but it shows no way to print the file directly to the printer.

Any Idea how to print QFile ??

Comment: QFile is to perform IO and filesystem related stuff, why should it have anything to do with printing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296021/how-to-print-pdf-file-in-qt

Answer (score 1):

The `QFile` class provides filesystem IO. In order to print a PDF file, you would have to parse its contents and render it onto a `QPrinter`.

So you would have to embed some kind of library for PDF rendering into your application. A popular open-source choice is the [Poppler library](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/), used for example by KDE's own PDF viewer Okular.

If that is too much hassle for you, there might be platform-dependent shortcuts. For example, on Unix/Linux systems, you can run the command `xdg-open /path/to/file.pdf` (e. g. using `QProcess`), which will open the standard PDF viewer. That could work if you instruct the user to choose the "Print" function in this application, but this requires extra user interaction.