# Printing a PDF file from Qt

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, printing, qsettings

I have found following code snippet which works as my expectation, but the problem is that, when a PDF file is open and user print the PDF file with some other printer from the PDF reader and not close the PDF reader and again print the PDF file from my application, it will print with printer which is configured on PDF reader not the printer which I set as to print the PDF file.

Example:

1. On application I set Printer_1 as to print PDF file.
2. Print the file (it will open the file in PDF reader and print with Printer_1 printer).
3. On PDF reader I go to `CTRL + P` to print and there I select Printer_2 and click on print.
4. I don't close the PDF reader and again on application (printer is selected to Printer_1), I print the PDF file. Now the print command is sent to Printer_2 instead of Printer_1.

Please what is the problem in the following code snippet?

```
#include <QSettings>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const QString classesRoot = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT";

    // get ID of .pdf extension
    QSettings pdfSettings(classesRoot + "\\.pdf", QSettings::NativeFormat);
    QString pdfId = pdfSettings.value("Default").toString();

    // get path to default program that associated with PDF files
    QString printPath = QSettings(classesRoot + "\\" + pdfId + "\\shell\\print\\command", QSettings::NativeFormat).value("Default").toString();
    QString openPath = QSettings(classesRoot + "\\" + pdfId + "\\shell\\open\\command", QSettings::NativeFormat).value("Default").toString();
    qDebug() << "print path" << printPath;
    qDebug() << "open path" << openPath;

    // open .pdf file
    QProcess::startDetached(openPath.arg("full path to pdf file.pdf") );

    // print .pdf file
    QProcess printProcess;
    printProcess.start(printPath.arg("full path to pdf file.pdf") );
    printProcess.waitForFinished(-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of line

```
QString printPath = QSettings(classesRoot + "\\" + pdfId + "\\shell\\print\\command", QSettings::NativeFormat).value("Default").toString();
```

use this and all works as expected:

```
QString printPath = QSettings(classesRoot + "\\" + pdfId + "\\shell\\printto\\command", QSettings::NativeFormat).value("Default").toString();
```

And pass "filename", "printer name" ,"printer driver" and "port"  [driver name and port are not mandatory]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I'd said that this seems reasonably to be the expected behaviour: if the application is already open and it is designed not to open separate instances for the same file (as many viewers do and as yours does), then is highly probable that current settings (in your case, the current printer) are preserved too, since, basically, nothing has changed. If you reproduce your steps but replacing your program by your own manual opening of the PDF file, I'm quite confident that you'll see the same results.

An option would be to avoid opening an external viewer and directly load the PDF file (currently using a third-party library, such as [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/)) and print it using Qt's modules. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8297239/1485885) for more information about it.